# Full height column with responsive image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I´m pretty new in html/css and I´m working right now with Bootstrap 3. I´m trying split the entire page in 2 columns with full height. The first column has an image (responsive), and in the other column I want to put some text.
My problem is that my image is  not taking the full height (with size up to 990px)and don´t find any way to solve this problem...:(
I´m looking something like that

http://levikoop.me/

Any idea??

Thanks guys!

**HTML**

```html
<div class="container-fluid no-padding">
      <!-- /container -->
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-6 no-padding" id="pic" >
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/uploads/1413548921627cb0e00f3/80652197?q=80&fm=jpg&w=1080&fit=max&s=6ce05e3ae3469356b9b0961c38386eec" class="img-responsive">
        </div> 

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div> <!-- /container -->
```

**CSS**

```css
html, body{
 height:100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

/*.navbar {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-color: transparent;
 padding-right: 90px;
}*/

.no-padding{
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;

}


.container-fluid{
 min-height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#pic{
 margin-bottom: -9999px;
 padding-bottom: 9999px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I can help; I'm not exactly sure what you're question is specifically about, but if I'm not mistaken you are wanting a solution to the image being too short and also for the second column to be to the right.

If so, try this:

To get the column effect, I've used left floats in the code below, and cleared them with a clearfix div beneath.

A potential solution for the short image, pick a background color to place under the image and fade the edges of the image to match that color.

```css
html, body{
 height:100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

/*.navbar {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-color: transparent;
 padding-right: 90px;
}*/

.no-padding{
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;

}

.col-md-6left {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background: #222222;
}

.clear-fix {
    clear: both;
}

.col-md-6right {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.container-fluid{
 min-height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#pic{
 margin-bottom: -9999px;
 padding-bottom: 9999px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid no-padding">
      <!-- /container -->
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-6left no-padding" id="pic" >
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/uploads/1413548921627cb0e00f3/80652197?q=80&fm=jpg&w=1080&fit=max&s=6ce05e3ae3469356b9b0961c38386eec" class="img-responsive">
        </div> 

        <div class="col-md-6right">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
         </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
      </div>  
    </div> <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: Thanks CodeLyfe for your reply. But I have run the snippet and I can´t see any change... is working like my code...

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/vzwa2fjL/7/

HTML

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="left">

    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.section {
    height: 100vh;
}

.left {
    background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/uploads/1413548921627cb0e00f3/80652197?q=80&fm=jpg&w=1080&fit=max&s=6ce05e3ae3469356b9b0961c38386eec');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    float: left;
}

.left, .right {
    width: 50vw;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**EDIT**

You can also do this using JQuery. Here is  https://jsfiddle.net/vzwa2fjL/12/

JS

```
$(window).resize(setHeightAndWidth);
$(document).ready(setHeightAndWidth);

function setHeightAndWidth() {
    $('.section').height($(window).height());
    $('.left, .right').width($(window).width() / 2 - (15));
}
```

CSS

```
.left {
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1920x980/000000/ffffff');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    float: left;
}

.left, .right {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nenad! your solution works fine! The key is to use vh and vw units ;)

Comment: Glad i could help, also instead of vw and vh you can use jquery to get same results.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!. Could you let me know a bit more about jquery trick? Thanks mate